# Passing argument (reference) to SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, httpserver

I've put together the following simple script that displays an image from the filesystem. The image that is shown can be switched by a GET request to a `HTTPServer` running in a separate thread.

It all works, but storing the reference to the UI object in global scope and then referring to it from the `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` seems quite hacky and messy. Is there a way to pass a UI reference or show_image callback to the Handler? Or a better way to structure this entirely? Any ideas would be appreciated.. thanks!

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf, GObject
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
from http.server import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from threading import Thread
import os
import signal

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

IMAGE_DIRECTORY = 'images'
PORT = 8000


class ThreadingSimpleServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass


class Handler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        response = 200 if ui.show_image(self.path[1:]) else 500
        self.send_response(response)
        self.end_headers()


class UI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.window.connect('destroy', self.quit)
        self.window.set_default_size(640, 480)
        self.background = Gtk.Image()
        self.window.add(self.background)
        self.server = ThreadingSimpleServer(('', PORT), Handler)

    def run(self):
        self.window.show_all()
        self.show_image('bird.jpg')
        Thread(target=self.server.serve_forever).start()
        Gtk.main()

    def show_image(self, image_name):
        image_path = os.path.join(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, image_name)
        try:
            pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(
                image_path,
                width=640,
                height=480,
                preserve_aspect_ratio=False)
            self.background.set_from_pixbuf(pixbuf)
            return True
        except:
            return False

    def quit(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

ui = UI()
ui.run()
```